# How do I write a Class-Based Django Validator?

Tags: python, django, validation, class, oop

I'm using Django 1.8.

The [documentation on writing validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#writing-validators) has an example of a function-based validator. It also says the following on using a class:

> You can also use a class with a `__call__()` method for more complex or configurable validators. RegexValidator, for example, uses this technique. If a class-based validator is used in the validators model field option, you should make sure it is serializable by the migration framework by adding `deconstruct()` and `__eq__()` methods.

- What are the pros/cons of class-based against function-based validators?
- What is `__call__()` used for, and how is it used?
- What is `deconstruct()` used for, and how is it used?
- What is `__eq__()` used for, and how is it used?

An example would be helpful. A full answer may also be worth submitting to be in the official documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

A big advantage of validator functions is that they are really simple. They simply take one value as an argument, check that it's valid, and and raise `ValidationError` if it's not. You don't need to worry about `deconstruct` and `__eq__` methods to make migrations work.

The `validate_even` example in the docs is much simpler than a validator class would be.

```
def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError('%s is not an even number' % value)
```

If you need to check divisibility by other numbers as well, then it would be worth creating a validator class `ValidateDivisibleBy`. Then you could use `ValidateDivisibleBy(2)`, `ValidateDivisibleBy(3)` and so on. But a lot of the time, a validator function is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Other than being able to inherit from `BaseValidator`, there might not necessarily be a significant pro/con to choosing function vs class-based validators. I prefer class-based because you can keep internal state if necessary without making it visible to the clients (e.g. compiled regexes, pre-computed values in a table, history, etc.)

The `__call__` method makes an object *callable* and allows it to sort of emulate function-like behavior (i.e. the object can be called like a function would), and the object's `__call__` override will be invoked. It requires you to implement the special `__call__(self, ...)` method in the validator.

```
class Callable(object):
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print('Calling', args, kwargs)

>>> c = Callable()
>>> c(2, 3, color='red')
Calling (2, 3) {'color': 'red'}
>>>
```

The `deconstruct` method seems to provide a point where the client (i.e. you) can override serializing behavior by writing custom implementations. For example, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#custom-deconstruct-method). This seems similar to the `clean` method, where you can implement custom input sanitation for your models and gets called automatically when `full_clean` is invoked (e.g. when a form uses `is_valid`).

The `__eq__` allows you to implement a comparison between 2 objects that are themselves not comparable. For example, if you have a

```
class Vector2:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

your `__eq__` implementation could look like this to check for equality between two vector objects:

```
# ...
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

This way, you avoid a shallow comparison of the underlying references.

Answer (score 1):

Starts from the beginning, there are almost none cons - except of maybe some complexity in implementing class based validators.

But there are some pros: yon can save in class instance something for future validation, so it won't be computed each time something is validated, for example compiled regex pattern. You can also create more complex validator by spreading code into other methods in your class.

Also, you can construct your validator with some parameters which can be used later in validation process.

`__call__` method is actual validation function - it will be called like normal validation function with same parameters (and additional `self` parameter - instance of class, like in all methods). And it's not something from django framework, it's from python itself. Any class can be called, like a function, if it has `__call__` method implemented. `deconstruct` method is explained in [migration serializing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing). `__eq__` is also from python itself, each class can have that and it will simply compare 2 objects to check if they are equal.