# How to use validators on FileField content

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

In my model, I want to use a validator to analyze the content of a file, the thing I can not figure out is how to access the content of the file to parse through it as the file has not yet been saved (which is good) when the validators are running.

I'm not understanding how to get the data from the `value` passed to the validator into a file (I assume I should use `tempfile`) so I can then open it and evaluate the data.

Here's a simplified example, in my real code, I want to open the file and evaluate it with csv.

in Models.py

```
class ValidateFile(object):
    ....
    def __call__(self, value):
        # value is the fieldfile object but its not saved
        # I believe I need to do something like:
        temp_file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        temp_file.write(value.read())
        # Check the data in temp_file
    ....

class MyItems(models.Model):
    data = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path,
                            validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['cv']),
                            ValidateFile()])
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look how this is done in the [ImageField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/fields.py#L620) implementation:

So your `ValidateFile` class may be something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO

class ValidateFile(object):

    def __call__(self, value):
        if value is None:
            #do something when None
            return None

        if hasattr(value, 'temporary_file_path'):
            file = value.temporary_file_path()
        else:
            if hasattr(value, 'read'):
                file = BytesIO(value.read())
            else:
                file = BytesIO(value['content'])

        #Now validate your file
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `tempfile`:

The `value` passed to a `FileField` validator is an instance of `FieldFile`, as already mentioned by the OP.

Under the hood, the `FieldFile` instance might already use a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L61)), or it might wrap an [in-memory file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L78), but you need not worry about that:

To "evaluate the data" you can simply treat the `FieldFile` instance as any Python [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object).

For example, you could iterate over it:

```
def my_filefield_validator(value):
    # note that value is a FieldFile instance
    for line in value:
        ... # do something with line
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile) says:

> In addition to the API inherited from `File` such as `read()` and `write()`, `FieldFile` includes several methods that can be used to interact with the underlying file: ...

and the `FieldFile` class provides

> ... a wrapper around the result of the `Storage.open()` method, which may be a `File` object, or it may be a custom storage’s implementation of the `File` API.

An example of such an underlying file implementation is the `InMemoryUploadedFile` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile)/[source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L78).

Also from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File):

> The `File` class is a thin wrapper around a Python file object with some Django-specific additions

Also note: [class-based validators vs function-based validators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32140052)